# Need to understand asynchronous usage of Spring WebClient

Tags: spring-boot, asynchronous, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I have a doubt regarding the usage of webclient in cirumstances when you need to invoke another service which is slow in responding and then use its data to process something and return in the call to your own api.
e.g. my doSometing method is called by service to retrive top order from a list.My service fetches the list from another service "order-service"

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    private TestService testService;

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String  doSomething() {  
         return WebClient.create()
                .get()
                .uri("http://localhost:9090/order-service")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(List.class)
                .block().get(0).toString();

//may be do more processing on the list later.
 
    }
```

As you can see , it currently blocks the calling thread which beats the purpose of async.Also , in future i might need to do more processing on this List before returning.
Am i using webclient correctly(is it serving any purpose here)?

Comment: If you are using WebFlux then you should rather return Mono<String> in the controller.

Comment: unfortunately no, the caller of this controller api needs a String.That is the point of my query.

Comment: who/what is the caller of the controller api? why does it need a string?

Comment: A legacy java service owned by some other team.

Comment: Is it calling your API via HTTP? If it does so, then you can safely return Mono<String> in your controller. In terms of HTTP response there won't be any difference.